# Meteor accounts sign-out not working after deploy without refreshing page

Tags: meteor, modulus.io

I am using Meteor with the accounts package. My deployment host is Modulus. When I deploy a new version to Modulus the app eventually reloads in the browser. If I try to click sign-out nothing happens. Other functionality of the app also seems to be broken. I have to refresh the page before the sign-out works again.

If I do a Meteor.disconnect() followed by a Meteor.reconnect() after the app has been reloaded that also seems to help.

Has anyone else seen this issue or know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being an issue with Fastrender and not subscribing to the user data at the right way.

Need to subscribe the user to their Meteor.user data